# How to register service worker using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm implementing a ReactJS web application using webpack and I want to start implementing a service worker to handle the network calls, in order to cache files. However, I find it hard to register the service worker javascript file. (I should add that I'm a beginner when it comes to both React and webpack.)

If I get it right, webpack merges every javascript file into one `bundle.js` file, which makes it hard to call `navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')...`. I have tried different approaches, such as [serviceworker-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serviceworker-webpack-plugin), but without luck. If I follow the steps provided on the readme page, I get an error message saying `Uncaught Error: serviceworker-webpack-plugin: It seems that your are importing "serviceworker-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime" without using the plugin. Makes sure that your webpack configuration is correct.`.

Here's my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
import ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015','react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin({
      entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/sw.js'),
      excludes: [
        '**/.*',
        '**/*.map',
        '*.html',
      ],
      filename: 'sw.js'
    })
  ]
}
```

Note: I used the `create-react-app` command to get going. Also, I have no issues with the service worker itself, I have a working implementation for another web app. It's just registering it I'm struggling with.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I found it easy to register a vanilla js service worker by putting it into its own file and adding it as an entry point in my webpack config. I would like to dive deeper into a react specific service worker which listens and re-renders a given component if an online/offline event is triggered. Like yourself i'm quite new to react and I'm wondering if redux is the way forward for this kind of behaviour. Redux is something I'm still struggling with though!

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/progressive-web-application/

Answer (score 27):

To remove the error, change the

```
import ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin';
```

to

```
var ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin = require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin');
```

Also note that the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serviceworker-webpack-plugin) has a typo:

```
plugins: [
new ServiceWorkerWebbackPlugin({
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/sw.js'),
}),
],
```

Notice that **Webpack** is spelled incorrectly here. It should be **Webpack** instead of **Wepback**.

Also, the docs stated that to register the Service Worker on main JS thread using the following code:

```
import runtime from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin/runtime';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  const registration = runtime.register();
}
```

However, upon closer inspection, it seems that the runtime directory is wrong. Checking the **node_modules** folder,

[image: runtime location]

It seems that the **runtime.js** is inside the **lib** folder. So, to fix this, change the

```
import runtime from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin/runtime';
```

to

```
import runtime from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime';
```

Once I did this, I managed to get the Service Worker installed on my dev environment.

[image: sw.js]

I'm still learning React + Webpack though! Also still figuring out a way to use Service Worker properly in my React app. I've also informed the author of this plugin of these required changes in the documentation. Hope it helps others!

Comment: i dont know why i have webpack bootstrap code in my sw.js now

Comment: @Nicholas Lie, how do I use the default serviceWorker.js here? it's giving me error with the window object when i'm using the above plugin.

Answer (score -7):

Create a project with create-react-app and then do some changes in package.json for adding service worker in your project.

It will guide you how to setup service worker in your project  and you don't need to create your own Webpack create-react-app command will do automatically

Please visit:https://github.com/jeffposnick/create-react-pwa#adding-in-a-github-deployment-step